# how to remove span from pageBlockSection

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have one pageblocksection.[image]

i want to remove Required information displaying on right hand side.
Thanks.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Personal Data">
   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
    <apex:repeat value="{!Info}" var="application">
      <apex:repeat value="{!Fields}" var="app">
    <apex:inputField  value="{!application[app.fieldPath]}" required="      {!OR(app.required, app.dbrequired)}"/>
  </apex:repeat>
 </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Can you please share your code of Visualforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what @techtrekker was getting at by putting an id on the pageBlockSection and then changing the jQuery selector to use that in conjunction with the *requiredLegend* class (see below).  However, anytime you rely on behind the scenes CSS you risk that SF will change it at some point making your page break.  You might want to push back on the requirement a little with an explanation that the required information text is standard functionality.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   $j(document).ready(function() {
       // note that there is a space before the .requiredLegend
       $j('[id$="myBlock"] .requiredLegend').hide();
   });
</script>

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Personal Data" id="myBlock">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the the text that appears on a standard page layout, from View Source, it is a span with class=requiredText

You can hide it using jQuery

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('.requiredText').hide();
```

This would hide all elements where the class was requiredText

Comment: but i want to do this only on 1 pageblock section.rest i want the same.

Comment: If its the first occurrence, you can use the first jQuery selector http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a much easier *without any javascript code* if you just change the `mode` parameter of `apex:pageBlock` from `edit` to **`detail`**, and then sets `collapsible="false"` for the `pageBlockSection`:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="detail" tabStyle="account">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Personal Data" collapsible="false">
```

With `mode="edit"` :

[image]

And with `mode="detail"` :

[image]

Comment: That is much better if the whole page or pageBlock is using it and it is acceptable for an edit page to be styled like a detail page, but I think in this case he just wanted one of the pageBlockSections to change.